# MySQL GROUP BY end of period

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

I am trying to average the 'value' column grouped into 4 hour end periods (4am, 8am, 12pm). I am using MySQL version 5.7.

An example table and data are below:

```
CREATE TABLE TestData(
    Timestamp DATETIME,
    Value FLOAT
);


INSERT INTO TestData
(Timestamp, Value)
VALUES
('2017-08-15 00:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 00:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 00:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 00:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 01:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 01:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 01:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 01:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 02:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 02:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 02:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 02:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 03:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 03:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 03:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 03:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 04:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 04:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 04:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 04:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 05:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 05:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 05:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 05:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 06:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 06:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 06:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 06:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 07:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 07:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 07:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 07:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 08:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 08:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 08:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 08:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 09:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 09:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 09:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 09:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 10:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 10:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 10:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 10:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 11:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 11:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 11:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 11:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 12:00:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 12:15:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 12:30:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 12:45:00', RAND()),
('2017-08-15 12:45:00', RAND());
```

I want to round to the next time period (therefore using the greater than).
When I run the following query:

```
SELECT
    Timestamp,
    ROUND(AVG(Value), 3) AS Value
FROM
    TestData
WHERE
    Timestamp > '2017-08-15 00:00:00' AND Timestamp <= '2017-08-15 12:00:00'
GROUP BY
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( Timestamp ) DIV 14400; -- 14400 seconds = 4 hours
```

This returns:

```
+---------------------+-------+
| Timestamp           | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2017-08-15 00:15:00 | 0.244 |
| 2017-08-15 01:00:00 | 0.478 |
| 2017-08-15 05:00:00 | 0.439 |
| 2017-08-15 09:00:00 | 0.499 |
+---------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I would like:

```
+---------------------+-------+
| Timestamp           | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2017-08-15 04:00:00 | 0.244 |
| 2017-08-15 08:00:00 | 0.478 |
| 2017-08-15 12:00:00 | 0.439 |
+---------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Could someone please let me know how this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What if my RAND values don't match yours? That's not very useful, is it?

Comment: The values themselves do not matter - As long as the group by averages are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP
  , ROUND(AVG(VALUE), 3) AS VALUE
FROM 
 testdata 
WHERE 
   HOUR(TIMESTAMP) >= 4
 AND 
  HOUR(TIMESTAMP) <= 12 
GROUP BY 
 FLOOR(HOUR(TIMESTAMP) / 4)
```

**Result**

```
timestamp             Value  
-------------------  --------
2017-08-15 04:00:00     0.500
2017-08-15 08:00:00     0.441
2017-08-15 12:00:00     0.527
```

Comment: Note that this actually returns an indeterminate value for TIMESTAMP (as can be kind of demonstrated if you replace FLOOR with CEILING) - but it may not materially affect the result.